# Significant difference in time while populating arrays (Coldfusion vs Railo)

Tags: arrays, performance, coldfusion, cfml, railo

During some development I ran into the issue of concatenating string which seems slow when doing it manually instead of a native function

```
<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfset dummyArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfset concatedString = "" />
<cfset concatenatedByFunctionString = "" />


<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="i">
       <cfset arrayAppend(dummyArray, RandRange(1000000, 9999999)) />
</cfloop>


<cfoutput>Prepping data: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="j">
       <cfset concatedString = concatedString & dummyArray[j] />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>concatenating data in loop: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>

<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfset concatenatedByFunctionString = arraytoList(dummyArray,'')/>
<cfoutput>concatenating data in arraytoList function: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfif structKeyExists(url,'debug')>
       in loop:<br/>
       <cfdump var="#concatedString#"/>
       in function:<br/>
       <cfdump var="#concatenatedByFunctionString#"/>
</cfif>
```

This is not the issue however. When you run this script in Coldfusion the time taken to prep the data is around 150ms, in Railo this is over 3000ms. When replacing the ArrayAppend with a cfset the loop gets much faster.

Any idea on what I do wrong?

edit: after some additional testing we came with the following results:

script used:

```
<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="10000" index="i">
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>Empty loop 10 000: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="i">
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>Empty loop 100 000: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="i">
       <cfset local.tmp = 1/>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>loop 100 000 cfset: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfscript>
       string = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.String");
       array = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.reflect.Array");
       dummyArray = array.newInstance(string.getClass(), 10000);
</cfscript>
<cfloop from="0" to="9999" index="i">
       <cfset array.set(dummyArray, i, "00000") />
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>loop 10 000 java array set: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfset dummyArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="i">
       <cfset arrayAppend(dummyArray, '00000') />
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>loop 100 000 arrayAppend: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>


<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfset dummyArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfloop from="1" to="100000" index="i">
       <cfset dummyArray[i] = '00000' />
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>loop 100 000 array set via brackets: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds<br/></cfoutput>
```

output:

Railo (4.2.1.008 final):
Empty loop 10 000: 0.001 seconds
Empty loop 100 000: 0.013 seconds
loop 100 000 cfset: 0.05 seconds
loop 10 000 java array set: 8.095 seconds
loop 100 000 arrayAppend: 1.96 seconds
loop 100 000 array set via brackets: 2.103 seconds

Adobe CF 10:
Empty loop 10 000: 0.002 seconds
Empty loop 100 000: 0.059 seconds
loop 100 000 cfset: 0.115 seconds
loop 10 000 java array set: 0.014 seconds
loop 100 000 arrayAppend: 0.139 seconds
loop 100 000 array set via brackets: 0.15 seconds

Any Insight / idea on this?

Thanks.

edit2:

my *real world* issue:

```
<cfinclude template="/queries/pr_web_shop_country_seo.cfm" >
<cfloop query="qry_web_shop_country_seo">
    <cfif qry_web_shop_country_seo.generate_sitemap eq 1>

        <cfset types_to_generate = ArrayNew(1) />
        <cfset types_to_generate[1] = "PRODUCTS" />

        <cfset indexList = ArrayNew(1) />

        <cfset locale = qry_web_shop_country_seo.country_code />
        <cfset id_language = qry_web_shop_country_seo.id_language_default />
        <cfset file_suffix = "-" & replace(qry_web_shop_country_seo.url_domain,'.','-','ALL') & ((qry_web_shop_country_seo.url_suffix eq "")? "" : "-" & qry_web_shop_country_seo.url_suffix) />
        <cfinclude template="/queries/pr_seo_urls.cfm">

        <cfloop array="#types_to_generate#" index="type">

            <cfswitch expression="#type#">

                <cfcase value="PRODUCTS">

                    <cfset productData = ArrayNew(2)>
                    <cfset counter = 1>

                    <cfloop query="qry_seo_urls">
                        <cfif qry_seo_urls.source eq 'PRODUCT'>
                            <cfset arrayAppend(
                                    productData[Ceiling(counter/max_link_list)]
                                    ,url_prefix & qry_web_shop_country_seo.url_domain & qry_web_shop_country_seo.root & qry_seo_urls.seo_url)
                            />
                            <cfset counter = counter + 1 />
                        </cfif>
                    </cfloop>
                </cfcase>
            </cfswitch>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong; Railo's just slower than ColdFusion for this it seems. What sort of answer are you actually looking for here? Do you have a real world problem, or is this all just theoretical? If you have a real world problem, reword the question to focus just on that actual problem, not just loop-de-loop "performance" "tests".

Comment: We're building sitemaps with this principle. we're looping over 150.000 records approx. As for real life issues: if this is an issue on 100K loops i image the problem is the same on 500 loops, just not as big. If we can improve this by configuration or something else, this would mean we gain about 300x improvement, which I find very significant. That's the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: @KennyG. Cool. So revise the question text to actually ask that. Don't ask a theoretical question: ask a *real* question. That said, it might be more a question for Code Review in that case, if it's just the technique you're really asking about, not a "problem" per se. The only slow case you have there is the one using Java arrays, which is an odd thing to do anyhow, and over 100k iterations on an occasional script, 8sec is not much to worry about. Much less the 1-2sec using CFML arrays.

Comment: @AdamCameron Based on a quick scan of the post, it would need to be clarified before going to Code Review. On-Topic CR question: "Here is working code that is designed to do XYZ, I would like it to run faster, any suggestions?". Off-Topic CR question: "Here are potential approaches we've looked at/tried, these are the results, why are A and B faster than C and D? Would E/F be even faster?"

Comment: @AdamCameron: I know that the difference in time in the application itself can't be told on single interactions when handeling data for an end user. odds are you won't be handling 100K records in a loop for a front end user. We also tested the loops with 1K Records and in those tests railo seems faster: 0.002 vs 0.008 seconds. I do find it strange that if we multiply the data by 100 it goes from 4 times faster to 15 times slower. The same applies to Lucee by the way. But that's another matter.

Comment: @KennyG. I'm not suggesting it's not an valid & interesting topic, but this is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. At the moment you're not really asking a valid, *real world* question. However I've said that a few times now, so short of you actually doing something about it, I'm out.

Comment: If you're looking for the fastest solution, then I just tried `dummyArray = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList"); dummyArray.add("00000")` on Lucee 4.5 and that performs well.

Comment: @JohnWhish : I've just tested this and it does indeed provide a lot of improvement over the regular implementation. Thanks for this valuable answer. Can you post this as a solution? Thanks Kenny

Comment: I had the same "real world" issue recently (sitemaps) and was surprised to find that concatenating inside`cfsavecontent` was faster than using arrays to build strings: http://cfsimplicity.com/101/string-concatenation-in-lucee

Comment: @CfSimplicity : thanks for the info, i'll try that one in my next case. (i'm happy with the speeds we get from arraytolist as it is now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the fastest solution, then try using an `java.util.ArrayList`. I tried it on Lucee 4.5 and it performed well so may suit your needs.

```
<cfset start = gettickcount()>
<cfset dummyArray = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList")>

<cfloop from="0" to="9999" index="i">
    <cfset dummyArray.add("00000")>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
loop 10,000 java.util.ArrayList add: #(gettickcount() - start)/1000# seconds
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Looking at the "real world" code above, this isn't really the best candidate for performance improvements. It looks ot me like too much data is being fetched too many times, and the better solution would be to push more of the processing back to the DB, rather than making Railo weed it all out. This is why I asked for the question to be posed as "I have this specific issue which needs addressing" rather than predetermining what ought to be looked at, and then focusing on that. Which is, in this case, probably not the best approach from the outset.

Comment: Fair point, from the comments on the question, I made the assumption that they are trying to generate an XML sitemap file where you could be looping through lots of data. I tried to answer the question posed, although I take your point that there may be a bigger picture here.

Comment: Yeah, @john-whish, that was more directed at the OP than you. More a FYI for you.

Comment: @AdamCameron: i see your point in taking teh processing back to the db. But as the fetching itself is already over the wanted time limit, i dont want to make thinks heavier. Due to the setup of the seo urls system it's simply not possible (time and resources in real world solutions). Thats why i wanted a cfml solution as first choise. Given the fact that i have that solution now and have cut about 2/3rds of the processing time i'm happy with this.